# Why isn't padding working in my Bootstrap 5.3 page?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, padding

Why is `pe-5` not working?

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="bg-info">
    <div class="row text-white">
      <div class="col-md-6 p-4 pe-5 ">
        <h2 class="">Adhnan M Y</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome! I converted your code to a snippet and the `pe-5` is definitely adding padding to the right side of that `div`. Why do you think it's not working? Also, you don't need all those BootStrap JS links. The first one is the only one you need since `bundle` includes `popper` and `bootstrap`

Comment: I also tested your code, and as @disinfor previously mentioned, the padding at the end of the div is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the required `.container` or `.container-fluid` class on an element around your row, so the row's spacing causes horizontal page overflow. This could give the impression that your padding doesn't exist or is smaller than expected.

I've added a container class and background color to the heading to demonstrate that it does.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#example

```css
h2 {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="container-fluid bg-info">
    <div class="row text-white">
      <div class="col-md-6 p-4 pe-5 ">
        <h2 class="">Adhnan M Y</h2>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```